# How to add jars with spark-shell?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, read-eval-print-loop

I tried with these methods below:

```
>>./spark-shell –-jars /home/my_path/my_jar.jar
```

and inside the shell, I tried importing the package:

```
scala> import com.vertica.spark._
<console>:23: error: object vertica is not a member of package com
       import com.vertica.spark._
```

It doesn't work and also I tried removing slash( / ) from the path of the jar

```
>>./spark-shell –-jars home/my_path/my_jar.jar
```

It is still the same..there was a warning though

```
20/04/21 22:34:40 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
Setting default log level to "WARN".
To adjust logging level use sc.setLogLevel(newLevel). For SparkR, use setLogLevel(newLevel).
Spark context Web UI available at http://ubuntu:4040
Spark context available as 'sc' (master = local[*], app id = local-1587488711233).
Spark session available as 'spark'.
Welcome to
```

But on the other side, if I go inside the shell and try to add require with the same jar path, then it successfully imports:

```
scala> :require /home/my_path/my_jar.jar
Added '/home/my_path/my_jar.jar' to classpath.

scala> import com.vertica.spark._
import com.vertica.spark._
```

What am I missing on adding the jars with the spark-shell itself ?

Comment: Do you have any warnings while loading the jars ?

Comment: yes, i added in the question @BlueSheepToken

Comment: `./spark-shell –-jars /home/my_path/my_jar.jar` should work. What is the full command?

Answer (score 0):

This issue may be due to hadoop native issue try below source bashrc, you will be good.

```sh
export JAVA_LIBRARY_PATH=$HADOOP_HOME/lib/native:$JAVA_LIBRARY_PATH
```

and

```sh
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$HADOOP_HOME/lib/native:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```